# Fetching local/remote video via Python using AgoraRTC

Tags: python, webrtc, agora.io

I was not able to fetch the video frames from the local/remote stream.

These are the steps I have followed.

1. Setup a local stream (one-on-one/many voice calls) via the following link given in the documentation. - https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/start_call_audio_web?platform=Web
   We generate the appId and channel name which will be used in step 2 from the agora console.
2. Next, I have used the Agora-Python-Quickstart documentation/code to set up communication between the code and stream via AgoraRTC module. The sample code with slight modifications for modularity has been used which is available here -> https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Python-QuickStart.

Result: We get a success (0) return, as displayed in the sample/demo code, but I am not sure if we are connected.

3. Now once the channel is joined using the commands given, we try to capture the frames/stream. For this we use the code present in class MyVideoFrameObserver as a reference to capture frames.
   As mentioned in documentation that whenever a stream is started, the code would callback "onRenderVideoFrame" or "onCaptureVideoFrame", which eventually should allow/show the frame.
   **ISSUE - We are not getting these video frames and these callbacks are not getting executed** (tried printing after overriding both of the above functions)

References for MyVideoFrameObeserver- https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Python-QuickStart/blob/master/face_recognition/face_recog.py.

References for Documentation - https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Python-SDK/blob/master/agorartc.py (LINE 7024) & https://docs.agora.io/en/faqs/API%20Reference/cpp/classagora_1_1media_1_1_i_video_frame_observer.html

Comment: Where you able to join the channel from your python and web stream? Also, if your callback are not getting executed that means there might be some problem while initialising the SDK. Can you please share your SDK logs. You can also, share this on the Agora community slack channel: https://www.agora.io/en/join-slack/